# Opencart 3.0.2.3 - Autocomplete() function added to customer_group.php

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, opencart-3

Attempting to add some feauture to Customer Groups I got stuck when needing for the autocomplete function which will get products so I can add them to specific customer groups when needed that will be shown on their My Account page. I cannot find what Im missing in order to get the autocomplete to work since it not showing the list `<li>` like the autocomplete in Categories (Product --> Links). I can see the `<li>` list with Element Inspector of Product->Links Category but not on my custom Customer Groups Form.

To give more light, this is what I have donde so far:

**admin/controller/customer/customer_group.php**

```
public function autocomplete() {
        $json = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
            $this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

            $filter_data = array(
                'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
                'sort'        => 'name',
                'order'       => 'ASC',
                'limit'       => 5
            );

            $this->load->model('catalog/product');

            $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $json[] = array(
                    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                    'name'       => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
                );
            }
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

**admin/view/template/customer/customer_group_form.twig**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-product"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_product }}">{{ entry_product }}</span></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="product" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_product }}" id="input-product" class="form-control"/>
          <div id="product-customer" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;"> {% for product in products %}
            <div id="product-customer{{ product.product_id }}"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> {{ product.name }}
              <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="{{ product.product_id }}"/>
            </div>
          {% endfor %}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
  $('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
      'source': function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=customer/customer_group/autocomplete&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                json.unshift({
                    product_id: 0,
                    name: '{{ text_none }}'
                });

                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['product_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
      'select': function(item) {
          $('input[name=\'product\']').val('');

          $('#product-customer' + item['value']).remove();

          $('#product-customer').append('<div id="product-customer' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>');
      }
  });

  $('#product-customer').delegate('.fa-minus-circle', 'click', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
  });
  //--></script>
```

**admin/model/customer/customer_group.php**

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image, m.name AS manufacturer, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND pd2.quantity = '1' AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special, (SELECT points FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_reward pr WHERE pr.product_id = p.product_id AND pr.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "') AS reward, (SELECT ss.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "stock_status ss WHERE ss.stock_status_id = p.stock_status_id AND ss.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS stock_status, (SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE p.weight_class_id = wcd.weight_class_id AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS weight_class, (SELECT lcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "length_class_description lcd WHERE p.length_class_id = lcd.length_class_id AND lcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS length_class, (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r1 WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "review r2 WHERE r2.product_id = p.product_id AND r2.status = '1' GROUP BY r2.product_id) AS reviews, p.sort_order FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON (p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id) WHERE p.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        return array(
            'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
            'name'             => $query->row['name'],
            'description'      => $query->row['description'],
            'meta_title'       => $query->row['meta_title'],
            'meta_description' => $query->row['meta_description'],
            'meta_keyword'     => $query->row['meta_keyword'],
            'tag'              => $query->row['tag'],
            'model'            => $query->row['model'],
            'sku'              => $query->row['sku'],
            'upc'              => $query->row['upc'],
            'ean'              => $query->row['ean'],
            'jan'              => $query->row['jan'],
            'isbn'             => $query->row['isbn'],
            'mpn'              => $query->row['mpn'],
            'location'         => $query->row['location'],
            'quantity'         => $query->row['quantity'],
            'stock_status'     => $query->row['stock_status'],
            'image'            => $query->row['image'],
            'manufacturer_id'  => $query->row['manufacturer_id'],
            'manufacturer'     => $query->row['manufacturer'],
            'price'            => ($query->row['discount'] ? $query->row['discount'] : $query->row['price']),
            'special'          => $query->row['special'],
            'reward'           => $query->row['reward'],
            'points'           => $query->row['points'],
            'tax_class_id'     => $query->row['tax_class_id'],
            'date_available'   => $query->row['date_available'],
            'weight'           => $query->row['weight'],
            'weight_class_id'  => $query->row['weight_class_id'],
            'length'           => $query->row['length'],
            'width'            => $query->row['width'],
            'height'           => $query->row['height'],
            'length_class_id'  => $query->row['length_class_id'],
            'subtract'         => $query->row['subtract'],
            'rating'           => round($query->row['rating']),
            'reviews'          => $query->row['reviews'] ? $query->row['reviews'] : 0,
            'minimum'          => $query->row['minimum'],
            'sort_order'       => $query->row['sort_order'],
            'status'           => $query->row['status'],
            'date_added'       => $query->row['date_added'],
            'date_modified'    => $query->row['date_modified'],
            'viewed'           => $query->row['viewed']
        );
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT pd.name, p.product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store pts ON (p.product_id = pts.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND pts.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

    if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
        $sql .= " AND pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
    }

    $sql .= " GROUP BY p.product_id";

    $sort_data = array(
        'name',
        'sort_order'
    );

    if (isset($data['sort']) && in_array($data['sort'], $sort_data)) {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY " . $data['sort'];
    } else {
        $sql .= " ORDER BY sort_order";
    }

    if (isset($data['order']) && ($data['order'] == 'DESC')) {
        $sql .= " DESC";
    } else {
        $sql .= " ASC";
    }

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $query->rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need autocomplete for customer group, why you querying products? 
For customer group add function to the controller, for example to the new your module file: **admin/controller/extension/module/customer_group_module.php**

```
public function autocomplete() {
        $json = array();

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_customer_group'])) {
            $this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

            $results = $this->model_customer_customer_group->getCustomerGroups();

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $json[] = array(
                    'customer_group_id' => $result['customer_group_id'],
                    'name'              => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
                );
            }
        }

        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
    }
```

To this file also add to the `public function index()`  section this:

```
$data['user_token'] = $this->session->data['user_token'];

if (isset($this->request->post['customer_group_module_customer_group'])) {
                $data['customer_group_module_customer_group'] = $this->request->post['customer_group_module_customer_group'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('customer_group_module_customer_group')) {
                $data['customer_group_module_customer_group'] = $this->config->get('customer_group_module_customer_group');
            } else {
                $data['customer_group_module_customer_group'] = array();
            }

            $data['customer_groups'] = array();

            $this->load->model('customer/customer_group');

            foreach ($data['customer_group_module_customer_group'] as $customer_group_id) {
                $customer_group_info = $this->model_customer_customer_group->getCustomerGroup($customer_group_id);

                if ($customer_group_info) {
                    $data['customer_groups'][] = array(
                        'customer_group_id' => $customer_group_info['customer_group_id'],
                        'name'              => $customer_group_info['name']
                    );
                }
            }
```

Next you not need to create any model file to get customer groups just use existing and load it as you can see above:`$this->load->model('customer/customer_group');`

In you template file **admin/view/template/extension/module/customer_group_module.twig** add:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="customer-group"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ help_customer_group }}">{{ entry_customer_group }}</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="customer_group" value="" placeholder="{{ entry_customer_group }}" id="customer-group" class="form-control" />
                  <div id="module-customer-group" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                    {% for customer_group in customer_groups %} 
                      <div id="customer-group{{ customer_group['customer_group_id'] }}"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> {{ customer_group['name'] }} 
                        <input type="hidden" name="customer_group_module_customer_group[]" value="{{ customer_group['customer_group_id'] }}" />
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %} 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

And before `{{ footer }}` add jquery for customer groups not for product:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $('input[name="customer_group"]').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=extension/module/customer_group_module/autocomplete&user_token={{ user_token }}&filter_customer_group=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) {
                    response($.map(json, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item['name'],
                            value: item['customer_group_id']
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(item) {
            $('input[name=\'customer_group\']').val('');

            $('#module-customer-group' + item['value']).remove();

            $('#module-customer-group').append('<div id="module-customer-group' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="customer_group_module_customer_group[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>');
        }
    });

    $('#module-customer-group').delegate('.fa-minus-circle', 'click', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
//--></script>
```

This is tested and working.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the fast answer, I do query products because it is what I need to be listed on the custom Customer Group Form field, not to autocomplete the Customer Groups as I think your answer does. I store those products IDs on a custom column of customer_group table on the DB for later use on the Frontend under user My Account so they can access those particular items, imagine an item to buy a membership for X time. I will try your script and give a feedback. Again Thank you so much.

Comment: If you read my code carefully, you should understand how it works and reuse the similar where you want. If my answer is useful, do not forget mark it as useful.

Comment: Yep, thats what actually Im going to do after I saw it was working. Note that the script you put on the `public function index()` didn't worked for me but adding it to the `getForm()` function did the job. I wont forget to mark it useful is just I dont see an option for "Super Useful". LOL, Thank you so much for your time and help, really appreciated!

Comment: "Note that the script you put on the public function index() didn't worked for me but adding it to the getForm() " it's depend where you use that code. So in your case you are right. I have add just sample for module... So, it is good if you solve your issue.

Comment: Problem solved, also added limit and other filtering parameters to it. Now I can move on thanks to you, have a nice day/night in this San Valentine day!